# jquery-ajax : how to call a php file using ajax

Tags: jquery

ajax  call:

```
   $.ajax({
         url: $("form").attr('action'),
         type: "post",
         data: $("form").serialize(),
         dataType: "json",
     });
```

Comment: How you are calling this ajax code? did you use event.preventDefault()?

Comment: so what you want and what the problem you faced?

Comment: what means the url? You are already specifying form action link.

Comment: actually i link to another php file through ajax but i couldn't

Comment: no i didn't use preventdefault()

Comment: yes i specified a link in form action

Comment: i am new to use jquery ajax

Comment: I want to access admin to crud on datatable.php. I set a link from index.php(admin login page) to datatable.php

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of calling a variable in a php file
HTML:

```
<p id="one"></p>
<p id="two"></p>
<p id="three"></p>
<form>
    <input id="name_one" type="text" name="name_one">
    <input id="name_two" type="text" name="name_two">
    <input id="name_three" type="text" name="name_three">
    <button id="submit_btn" type="submit">Enter</button>
</form>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit_btn').on('click',function(){
        var val1 = $('#name_one).val(),
            val2 = $('#name_two).val(),       
            val3 = $('#name_three).val();
        $.ajax({
           url      : 'nameofyourphpfile.php',
           type     : 'POST',
           data     : {name1:val1,name2:val2,name3:val3}, 
           dataType : 'json',
           async    : false,
           success  : function(data){
                        $('#one').html(data.one);
                        $('#two').html(data.two);
                        $('#three').html(data.three);
           }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name1'],$_POST['name2'],$_POST['name3'])){
      $one = $_POST['name1'];
      $two = $_POST['name2'];
      $three = $_POST['name3'];

      //this code sends your php variable to your ajax
      $response['one'] = $one;
      $response['two'] = $two;
      $response['three'] = $three;

      echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```